# PostgreSQL aggregate union, intersection and set differences

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table of pairs to aggregate as follows:

```
+---------+----------+
| left_id | right_id |
+---------+----------+
| a       | b        |
+---------+----------+
| a       | c        |
+---------+----------+
```

And a table of values as so:

```
+----+-------+
| id | value |
+----+-------+
| a  | 1     |
+----+-------+
| a  | 2     |
+----+-------+
| a  | 3     |
+----+-------+
| b  | 1     |
+----+-------+
| b  | 4     |
+----+-------+
| b  | 5     |
+----+-------+
| c  | 1     |
+----+-------+
| c  | 2     |
+----+-------+
| c  | 3     |
+----+-------+
| c  | 4     |
+----+-------+
```

For each pair, I would like to calculate the length of the union, intersection and set differences (each way) comparing the values, so that the output would look like this:

```
+---------+----------+-------+--------------+-----------+------------+
| left_id | right_id | union | intersection | left_diff | right_diff |
+---------+----------+-------+--------------+-----------+------------+
| a       | b        | 5     | 1            | 2         | 2          |
+---------+----------+-------+--------------+-----------+------------+
| a       | c        | 4     | 3            | 0         | 1          |
+---------+----------+-------+--------------+-----------+------------+
```

What would be the best way to approach this using PostgreSQL?

UPDATE: here is a rextester link with data https://rextester.com/RWID9864

Comment: I don't understand what the "pairwise union" is supposed to be. Can you explain the logic what that is `5` for `a,b`?

Comment: The number of unique values if you combine all the values from a (1,2,3) and b (1,4,5). Union = (1,2,3,4,5) = 5 values. Intersection is (1) = 1 value, left diff (2,3) = 2 values, right diff (4,5) = 2 values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need scalar sub-queries that do that.

The UNION can also be expressed by an `OR` which makes that query somewhat shorter to write. But for the intersection you need a query that is a bit longer.

To calculate the "diff", use the `except` operator:

```
SELECT p.*, 
       (select count(distinct value) from values where id in (p.left_id, p.right_id)) as "union",
       (select count(*)
        from (
          select v.value from values v where id = p.left_id
          intersect
          select v.value from values v where id = p.right_id
        ) t) as intersection,
       (select count(*)
        from (
          select v.value from values v where id = p.left_id
          except
          select v.value from values v where id = p.right_id
        ) t) as left_diff,
       (select count(*)
        from (
          select v.value from values v where id = p.right_id
          except
          select v.value from values v where id = p.left_id
        ) t) as right_diff
from pairs p
```

Comment: Thank you for introducing me to "scalar subqueries". I had no idea there was such a thing. Another user posted a very similar solution a minute ago, however he/she noted that it could be quite inefficient. Unfortunately now deleted (which I really wished didn't happen as I was writing a response). Is there any way to make such a query more efficient? I suppose I could save the resulting table as a materialized view perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what causes your slowness, as I cannot see table sizes and/or explain plans. Presuming both tables are large enough to make nested loops inefficient and to not dare thinking about joining values to itself, I'd try to rewrite it free from scalar subqueries like this:

```
select p.*,
       coalesce(stats."union", 0) "union",
       coalesce(stats.intersection, 0) intersection,
       coalesce(stats.left_cnt - stats.intersection, 0) left_diff,
       coalesce(stats.right_cnt - stats.intersection, 0) right_diff
from pairs p
left join (
       select left_id,
              right_id,
              count(*) "union",
              count(has_left and has_right) intersection,
              count(has_left) left_cnt,
              count(has_right) right_cnt
       from (
              select p.*,
                     v."value" the_value,
                     true has_left
              from pairs p
              join "values" v on v.id = p.left_id
       ) l
       full join (
              select p.*,
                     v."value" the_value,
                     true has_right
              from pairs p
              join "values" v on v.id = p.right_id
       ) r using(left_id, right_id, the_value)
       group by left_id,
                right_id
) stats on p.left_id = stats.left_id
       and p.right_id = stats.right_id;
```

Each join condition here allows hash and/or merge join, so the planner will have a chance to avoid nested loops.

Comment: Very cool. Thank you @alexey-bashtanov and @a_horse_with_no_name both for your answers. I learned a lot from both of these. In the end, this solution performs slightly faster than "scalar subquery", completing in 1m17s versus 1m36s. It's a bit of a mess to show the query plans for my dataset because the `pairs` table is a view aggregating data from multiple tables (376 rows) so the plan is huge. The `values` table has 2,9 million rows btw. Too bad my question got downvoted.

Comment: in case pairs is such a small thing and aggregated from somewhere, maybe it would make sense to have a CTE for it, for it to be calculated only once. For plan optimization purposes, just create a temp table with the view contents and ANALYZE it, then use it instead of the view.